# Calling a closure inside a promise callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm implementing queue system for a webapp so that HTTP request that are failed are locally stored to be re-executed later on.

I have read Mozilla's documentation about [closure in loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake) and then created inner closures.

If running this with ids `[1,2,3]`, the output will be:

```
makeRequestRecovery 1
makeRequestRecovery 2
makeRequestRecovery 3
failure
recover id 1
failure 
recover id 1
failure
recover id 1
```

code:

```
var recoverRequest = function(entry) {
    console.log('recover id', entry.data.id);
    $scope.storage.entries.push(entry);
};

var makeRequestRecovery = function(entry) {
    console.log('makeRequestRecovery', entry.data.id);
    return function() {
        recoverRequest(entry);
    }
};

$scope.syncEntries = function() {

    var initialLength = $scope.storage.entries.length;
    var requestCount = 0;
    while ($scope.storage.entries.length > 0) {
        var entry = $scope.storage.entries.pop(0);
        var recover = makeRequestRecovery(entry);

        // restangular stuff...

        // restangular HTTP REMOVE
        entry.remove().then(function(data) {
            console.log('success!', data);
        }, function(data) {
            console.log('failure', data);
            recover();
        });

        requestCount++;
        if (requestCount > 2 * initialLength) {
            // too many requests failed
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What changes should I make so `recover()` is executed with the right value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually didn't use the closure properly.
`recover` needs to be passed as callback:

```
entry.remove().then(function(data) {
    console.log('success!', data);
}, recover);
```